Base setup modification after HF Installation using Wix
Scenario:
We have a base setup which has 2 packages
Package 1 with features A, B, C, D
Package 2 with features X, Y, Z
We performed the following steps
Step 1: Install the base setup by only selecting features A and B (only package 1 is installed and version 1 files are copied)
Step 2: Install Hot Fix on top of the base setup (only package 1 related msp is installed and version 2 files of features A and B are copied)
Step 3: Modified the base setup by including all features A. B. C. D. X, Y, Z
Actual result after Modify:
Version 2 files of features A, B, C, D are copied
Version 1 files of features X, Y, Z are copied
Log:
[F2BC:E014][2024-06-06T15:19:18]i201: Planned package: Package1, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[F2BC:E014][2024-06-06T15:19:18]i201: Planned package: Package2, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[F2BC:E014][2024-06-06T15:19:18]i207: Planned related bundle: {e6a583b1-a78f-46c5-b779-57610fc08de5}, type: Patch, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, dependency: Register

Our Bootstrapper failed the related bundle installation as the hotfix is already installed.
Can anyone please help me with the expected behavior for this scenario.
We did not prevent the HF installation and after base setup modification all the installed files are of version 2.
Expectation: I would like to understand the installation standards if there are any.
